# Trying to understand RxJS imports

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm having a hard time figuring out how exactly this import statement works (in an Angular application written in Typescript):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

I get that `rxjs` is mapped to the respective `node_modules` subfolder in the SystemJS config file, but then I'm stuck. I see that there is an index.js file but I don't see whether or how this helps to resolve the `add/operator/...` part.

Similarly, I don't understand this one:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Again, there is no file `Observable.*` file in this place. I guess that it somehow works via the index.js file but I'd really like to get a more thorough understanding because I read that it is easy to import all of RxJS by accident which increases page load times.

I had a closer look at the Typescript module resolution documentation but I have the feeling that this is not sufficient to explain it.

**Update:** After reading the accepted answer below I figured out I had been looking at the `node_modules/rx` directory instead of `node_modules/rxjs` so the import statements match perfectly with the directory structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty simple because TypeScript by default looks into `node_modules` directory.

Importing the following:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

is resolved as `node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts` which is enough to compile the code.

Similarly importing `rxjs/add/operator/toPromise` is resolved as `node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/toPromise.ts`. Btw you can use the `--traceResolution` compiler option to see what TypeScript path are tested.

When you have your compiled JS (eg. in `commonjs` format) you can run your app in `node` because it'll call `require('rxjs/Observable')` which will resolve to `node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js`. Then similarly with `rxjs/add/operator/toPromise`.

Be aware that the code structure of RxJS github page is different than the actual npm package. Basically, just the `package.json` and the [`src`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src) dir with compiled `.js` and `.d.ts` files are uploaded to the npm repository (the original `.ts` source files are in `node_modules/rxjs/src` but you never want to work directly with them).

Comment: Oh no, I was looking at the wrong directory... "rx" not "rxjs". Now it is perfectly clear, thanks!

Comment: Martin , why did they use `/add` prefix ? It doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Royi What doesn't make sense? All files in `/add/...` directory are used to add an operator to the `Observable.prototype` (eg. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/add/operator/buffer.ts). This allows using only those operators that I actually need in my prohject and therefore JS bundlers with tree-shaking (rollup.js, webpack2 and maybe more) can generate smaller bundles.

Comment: I don't know. Same like there's no '/add/angular/router' . The folder should not indicate the action