# What is the difference between the "rx" and "rxjs" npm packages?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

When trying to figure out how my RxJS import statements work, the presence of the `node_modules/rx` folder [caused some confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43651560/302793).

Now I am wondering why there are two separate packages at all. From the package descriptions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx) I can't really tell the difference. Is rx maintained by Microsoft and the other by a different community? Are there major differences? A link to a document with an explanation and some advice when to use which of them would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at this [link](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) you can find that:

> Note: RxJS v5 beta is being developed at
>   https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs.

In Short:

- RXJS - v5+
- RX - v4-

More about v5+ can be found [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs):

> This is a rewrite of Reactive-Extensions/RxJS and is the latest
>   production-ready version of RxJS. This rewrite is meant to have better
>   performance, better modularity, better debuggable call stacks, while
>   staying mostly backwards compatible, with some breaking changes that
>   reduce the API surface.